# Gnuplot: is there a way to add small gif icon on the plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am looking for a way to add small icons on the plot, like OK or KO symbols, flags, arrows and such.

So far I've seen an example where you can add a background image, but nothing that actually allow me to set a point on the plot, like I could do with a label, and apply there an icon.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call me obsessive but as usual this can be done with the `epslatex` terminal, embedding the image using a `set label` statement as you would do in regular latex. If your image is `so-icon.png`, then within gnuplot do:

```
set terminal epslatex standalone header "\\usepackage{graphicx}"
set output "plot.tex"
set label at screen 0.5,0.5 '\includegraphics{so-icon.png}'
plot sin(x)
```

And now run `pdflatex`

```
pdflatex plot.tex
```

Your output will be named `plot.pdf` and look like this:

[image]

Change the positioning of the label (`help set label` for more info) to wherever you want. You can also use the formatting options of `\includegraphics{}`, for example `\includegraphics[width=2cm]{}` for a 2cm wide version of your image (sorry, I don't do inches!).

Note that if you want to embed PNG, JPEG, GIF, PDF and so on, the `pdflatex` command is required, you cannot use regular `latex` for those.

Comment: Nice! Is also possible to render it with the png output mode, or works only with eps latex?

Comment: At least this way is PDF only, but of course there are many ways to convert PDF to PNG. Try the `convert` command or GIMP, just to name a couple.

Comment: good point; I can always convert the output to PNG outside Gnuplot. Thanks!