# Combining vector and raster images in gnuplot

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, figure, eps

Is there a way to combine a vector file with a raster file in gnuplot to get a single one? 
In particular, I have a spectrum of a chemical compound (.eps file) and would like to overlay structural formula of the compound (.png) at a given position in spectrum file (keeping the high quality of vector graphics in parts of resulting figure which are unobstructed by the formula).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need gnuplot? Do you generate the eps file with gnuplot? If yes, I think the best way is to use the `epslatex` terminal like shown in [Gnuplot: is there a way to add small gif icon on the plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24253276/2604213).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the multiplot feature in gnuplot to do this

e.g.

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color "Helvetica" 20
set output 'my_data.eps'

# beginning of multiplot
set multiplot

# the first plot
set size 1,1
set origin 0,0
set xlabel "Distance 1"
set ylabel "Distance 2"
set log x
set log y
set xrange[0.01:1]
plot    "my_data.m" title "" with p pt 5

# smaller overlay plot
set size 0.45,0.45
set origin 0.15,0.5
set xrange [:0.2]
set lmargin 5
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
unset arrow
unset logscale
set xtics 0.05
set ytics 0.2
set grid
plot    "my_data.m" title "" with p pt 5

# end of multiplot
unset multiplot
```

[Reference](http://modulo.com/2013/03/how-to-overlay-two-plots-in-gnuplot.html)

You may also find this link helpful : http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.2/image.html

Comment: http://www.adamcrume.com/blog/archive/2013/03/12/hybrid-bitmapvector-plots-with-gnuplot says you should convert the eps to a png using ImageMagick first

Comment: In general, your recommendation to convert an eps image to a png image is a bad choice. And it is the opposite of what the OP actually asked for (keep the vector image, i.e. the eps image, and include the png).